# How would you repair this window leak?

Tags: windows, leak, window-frame

I recently bought my first home and a few months ago when it rained heavily I noticed water leaking inside from under the bottom window molding.

I tried to recreate what was causing the leak and it happens when water is getting onto the sill and not from the master frame connection to the brick.

How do you recommend this be fixed? I've contacted a few window companies and most say the window needs to be resealed but I'm worried the problem is with the window itself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So if I understood correctly the water enters between the sill and the master frame. Why not seal it with silicone and this tool (don't know the word in English)?

Use plumbing silicone or other silicone used for moist environments. Place the silicone generously and detract it with the tool shown. This should seal it thoroughly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the source of the leak and stop it. I would start looking at the top of the window frame . Likely it is entering at the interface between the window frame and a wall ( on the exterior surface.)

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote, but it's entirely possible that water is entering at the top or sides on the outside, then exiting at the bottom on the inside.